# strtotime different result on localhost

Tags: php, strtotime

I use strtotime function like this:

> strtotime($from);

$from is that same on both servers (local and production) - 2013-10-01

but returned strtotime results are not that same.

on local (windows 8, wamp)  - 1380585600
on production (linux)  - 1380578400

Comment: they are in different timezones

Answer (score 3, accepted):

did you set the default timezone?

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
```

Comment: timezone on localhost was not that same as on production. Thx a lot